# How to Custom Folder Access when users Login using SFTP,SSH,SCP?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, openoffice

I have problem when I want to config my SSH server, I have username root and guest.

I want root still can access SSH and for guest users , only can transfer file (copy and paste) some directory.

in my problem is when I am login using guest users with SCP,SFTP,SSH it's possible to view my Filesystem in server,i think it's not good for security.

I want to make secure if Guest login using ssh,sftp,scp, only some folder I am configuration is showed, example (/var/www/site)

Any suggestion How I can make like that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new group, e.g. 'scponly'.
2. Create the target user accounts and set their home directory to the intended path, e.g. /var/www/site. Add these user accounts to group scponly.
3. Add this to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

   ```
   Match Group scponly
     ChrootDirectory %h
     ForceCommand internal-sftp
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     AllowAgentForwarding no
     X11Forwarding no
   ```

Now the users in group scponly will not be able to login to the system but only use SFTP/SCP. And they will be restricted to their home directory which will be shown as /.